# How to add to Android Studio those wallpapers that move with the movement of the cell phone?

Tags: android-studio

I'm making a wallpaper application in Android Studio, but I want to add one of those 3d wallpapers that move with the movement of the cell.

I've found a page called [DEPTHY](https://github.com/panrafal/depthy), which allows me to create the 3d effect I want. I have downloaded the images in PNG format and then converted them to stl format and from there to .`fbx` format for Android-Studio to accept it, but I think I'm doing it wrong. The point is that when I add it to the **res/drawable** path and add it to my code Android does not accept the `.fbx` or `.obj` extension.

This is the message I get:

[image: message]

I don't know if I'm adding it to the wrong folder or if the format is incorrect. I tried it with the `.gif` extension, but it doesn't have the desired effect.

Comment: Can you describe what is your desired effect? As I realized you have a git animation and want to show it. The dynamic effect of the mentioned tool only works on their website.